# How the local file structure should be on SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Question might sound weird. But here is the detailed question, I'm having branches, tags and trunk folder by default on my repository. What happens if I checkout the repo from `/trunk` instead of `/` (root)? Since I'm able to switch to any branch on my trunk folder, do I need the other folders to be present in my local computer?

Comment: "What happens if I checkout the repo from /trunk instead of /" - What else could you be doing? That's the usual way to work with the trunk. It doesn't make much sense to have a working copy that contains your entire repository. Imagine if you had 200 tags!

Comment: Well I was doing.. the way of copying the entire root. Thanks for the clarification